# Drag and drop to reorder <div> after appending them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two buttons

```
<a href="#" class="add">+ Add 1</a>
<a href="#" class="add2">+ Add 2</a>
```

By clicking them I can create as many divs I want. I made this possible by jQuery append() method.

But I am wanting to **reorder** and **arrange** this divs After I created them. 
like: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

I am bad in jQuery and  I am not sure if this is possible to make ? If yes then any help will be appreciated.

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jnLfh/14/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="holder">

    <div class="bar">
        <p style="float:left"> Hello world</p>
         <a href="#" style="float:right" class="delete"> remove </a>
    </div>
    <div class="bar2">
        <p style="float:left"> Hello world 2</p>
         <a href="#" style="float:right" class="delete"> remove </a>
    </div>


</div>


<a href="#" class="add">+ Add 1</a>
<a href="#" class="add2">+ Add 2</a>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.add').click(function() {
 $(".holder").prepend('<div class="bar"><p style="float:left"> Hello world</p> <a href="#" style="float:right" class="delete"> remove </a></div>');
});

$('.add2').click(function() {
 $(".holder").prepend('<div class="bar2"><p style="float:left"> Hello world</p> <a href="#" style="float:right" class="delete"> remove </a></div>');
});


$('.delete').click(function() {
 $(this).parent('.bar').remove();
});
```

Comment: How should they be re-ordered? What's the order?

Comment: Ii can be any order I can drag the any red or gray bars and re positioned them. For the Example I just added two different color. On my project there are many random divs . And I needed to have the ability to rearrange.

Comment: Well you have the documentation, why can't you just follow it? what have you tried according to it? this is not the place where people do things for you, but help you do it by solving the problems you encounter while trying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added jquery-ui:  jsfiddle.net/jnLfh/17

Comment: Actually not like this. I needed to have the ability to drag and drop like : https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: Okay, if you like it, why do not load jquery-ui? http://jsfiddle.net/jnLfh/17/ Here I added jquery-ui.js and made it sortable as in example. Plus added counters, they helps to understand what is happening.

Comment: Thanks Now I got the result !

Comment: I was just confused if I append jquery ui sort, will that work. Now I see this is working Great !